# How to add button inside listadapter view in android

Tags: android, listview, button, adapter

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailedlist_row, null);

    convertView.setClickable(true);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title); 

    TextView price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price); 
    TextView view = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewlistin); 
    TextView edit = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editlisting); 
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               String userid;
              // Toast.makeText(activity, "view clicked: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               Intent intent = new Intent(activity, review.class);
               activity.startActivity(intent); 

           }
       });

    final Movie m = movieItems.get(position); 
}
```

i set the `onclick` for `textview` inside the `adapter`, when i click the `textview` my app get force closed  can u guide me what is wrong with my code

Comment: please show the error log

Comment: remove `convertView.setClickable(true);`

Comment: Is your problem solved? If not then please post the error log.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a `ListView`? I can't tell by just looking at the code posted. If so, after creating it, you can create an `ArrayAdapter` and set the `adapter`.

**Here is an example:**

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

// Create The Adapter with passing ArrayList as 3rd parameter
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(First.this, R.layout.button, yourList);

// Set The Adapter
list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

// register onClickListener to handle click events on each item
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    // argument position gives the index of item which is clicked
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {
        String itemSelected = yourList.get(position);
        int quantity= yourList.size();
        for (int l=0;l<quantity;l++) {
            if(yourList.get(l)==itemSelected) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);

                // rest of code here
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
    }
});
```

Since you want to create a button for each item of the list, you can follow this tutorial on how to do this [button](https://youtu.be/_sStCBdJkQg).

Then you set the `R.layout.button` with the name of the layout (xml) you created for the button.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this way if am I right**

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.viewlistin);

    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (ThisClass.this, NextClass.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```